# How to click on Windows network taskbar icon using Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework, rpa

What should I put in xxx? Is this the right way of doing it?

```
***Settings***
Library   RPA.Desktop.Windows

***Variables***
${Network icon} =  xxxxxxxxxxx

***Tasks***
Click Element If Visible     ${Network icon}
```

Comment: I was trying to do the same but did not find any identifier for the taskbar icon. Ended up using the coordinates of the icon and click on it, which worked. Now I am struggling with making it work with headless windows server as it does not really have the screen attached to it.